# Sequelize update with association not updating table for the associated model

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, associations, sequelize.js

I have two tables below:
 1. `Poll`
 2. `Option`

The Poll model is as follows:

```
 const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
 let dbService = require('../services/dbService.js');

 let Option = require('./options');

 let Poll = dbService.define('Poll', {
 poll: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
 },
 isAnonymous: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
 },
 startDate: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
 },
 endDate: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
 },
 active: {
    type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,

 }
 });

 Poll.hasMany(Option);

 module.exports = Poll;
```

The Option model is as follows:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
let dbService = require('../services/dbService.js');

let Option = dbService.define("option", {
    name: Sequelize.STRING
});

module.exports = Option;
```

This is my /GET route for api/poll/:id

[image: This is my /GET route for api/poll/:id]

I want to update the poll. All the other routes are working fine. I am just stuck on updating the model.

The controller for /PUT api/poll/:id
[image]

The service for /PUT api/poll/:id
[image]

This only updates the Poll table, the Option table's column does not get updated. How can I achieve the update with the one to many association like this?

I have tried this too! [Sequelize update with association](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33960831/8140232)

I have even done the same as the sequelize docs. But I am unable to achieve what I want. I've been stuck on this for a while. Any kinda help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I think you might want to look out for your `ON UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For update you can try SequelizeModel.upsert() function.

Comment: Is not updating associated values