# Sequelize ignores WHERE condition on associated model for UPDATE method (does not build INNER JOIN part of query)

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to run `update` method on a model with a `WHERE` condition on main model and on an associated one. Sequelize ignores the nested `WHERE` condition and the whole association and generates a query that does not have the `INNER JOIN` element. Relevant: I want to update many records at once, so single instance methods are not what I'm looking for.

My query setup looks like this:

```
const setInstruction = {
    displayIndex: Sequelize.literal('displayIndex + 1')
};
const updateOptions = {
    where: {
        ID: { [Op.ne]: 1616 },
        displayIndex: { [Op.and]: { [Op.lt]: 7, [Op.gte]: 3 } }
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: models.Component,
            required: true,
            attributes: [],                
            include: [
                {
                    model: models.ObjectType,
                    attributes: [],
                    required: true,
                    where: { objectType: 'Task' }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
};
return models.UserComponent.update(setInstruction, updateOptions);
```

It generates this SQL query:

```
UPDATE `user_components` SET `displayIndex` = displayIndex + 1, `updatedAt` =? WHERE`ID` != 1616 AND(`displayIndex` < 7 AND`displayIndex` >= 3);
```

As you can see the `INNER JOIN` is missing and obviously only the main `WHERE` conditions are included. For some reason also `'updatedAt' =?` is added, don't know why. The query runs and performs update, no error is thrown, but of course too many records are impacted, because of the missing condition.

What can be wrong? What am I missing?

The `updateOptions` config does work in a `findAll` method and does generate proper query with `INNER JOIN`s.

I also tried different syntax and put the condition to the main `WHERE` statement like this:
`'$component.object_type.objectType$': 'Task'`
It works for `findAll`, but in update throws error `Unknown column 'component->object_type.objectType' in 'where clause'`

My models are defined like this:

```
const UserComponent = connectionPool.define('user_component', {
    ID: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    }  
}, {
    defaultScope: {
        attributes: { exclude: ['createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'componentID', 'userID', 'ID'] }
    }
});
const Component = connectionPool.define('component', {
    ID: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    }  
}, {
    defaultScope: {
        attributes: {
            exclude: ['createdAt', 'updatedAt']
        }
    }
}
);
const ObjectType = connectionPool.define('object_type', {
    ID: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    objectType: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    defaultScope: {
        attributes: { exclude: ['createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'ID'] }
    }
});
```

And the associations:

```
models.Component.belongsTo(models.ObjectType, { foreignKey: 'objectTypeID', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
models.Component.hasMany(models.UserComponent, { foreignKey: 'componentID', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
models.UserComponent.belongsTo(models.Component, { foreignKey: 'componentID', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
```

How to make Sequelize add the `INNER JOIN` condition? I went through many questions and the docs and it seems to me I am doing everything correctly. What am I missing? I will apreciate any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sequelize update with association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918383/sequelize-update-with-association)

Comment: Not really, it's a workaround for updating single object, I want to update many at once and avoid forEach if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'update' method does not support 'include' option. See https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-update. You should get all IDs of the models you wish to update (using findAll) and then update them using [Op.in] and IDs array.

```
const searchOptions = {
    where: {
        ID: { [Op.ne]: 1616 },
        displayIndex: { [Op.and]: { [Op.lt]: 7, [Op.gte]: 3 } }
    },
    attributes: ['ID'],
    include: [
        {
            model: models.Component,
            required: true,
            attributes: [],                
            include: [
                {
                    model: models.ObjectType,
                    attributes: [],
                    required: true,
                    where: { objectType: 'Task' }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
};

const modelsToUpdate = await models.UserComponent.findAll(searchOptions)
const updateOptions = {
    where: {
        ID: { [Op.in]: modelsToUpdate.map(x => x.ID) }
    }
}
return models.UserComponent.update(setInstruction, updateOptions);
```

Comment: That's disappointing... I'm pretty sure I saw some example in docs (in a different section though) and certailny in some answers here on Stackoverflow. I'll go the longer way then. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose it's because such UPDATE statement with JOIN is non-standard and different vendors have its own extensions of SQL to work with JOIN in UPDATE statement.

Comment: I see, I didn't know  about such differencies. It makes (some) sense then. Do you know any good low level MySQL library that could help in cases like this? By low level I mean no instantialization and all that fancy stuff, just composing SQL script from JS objects. Sequelize seems to cause more and more problems the more advanced things you need to do. Pure SQL might be simpler, but I really hate the idea of builidng a script from strings.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll look at it. For some reason I thought that's just another Sequelize-style ORM. But I'll gladly find out that I was mistaken!